# CMake: Shared library can't find it's own include directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a library which is structured like this:

```
/mylib
-> /include
  -> /camera
    -> Camera.h
-> /src
  -> /camera
    -> Camera.cpp
  -> CMakeLists.txt
```

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I define the path to include directories as relative path to the `src` directory:

```
add_library(mylib SHARED
    camera/Camera.cpp
)
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC ../include)
```

Everything works up to this point. Building library as standalone component yields correct result. But when I try to add `mylib` into another project, suddenly the library stops finding the includes directory:

```
/main_project/mylib/src/camera/Camera.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'camera/Camera.h' file not found
#include "camera/Camera.h"
```

I also tried using `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` but it doesn't seem to work too.

**Edit:**
I figured it out, by adding the include directories of the `mylib` to the `main_project` I managed to proceed with the build process:

```
target_include_directories(
  main_project
  PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib/include
)
```

Comment: Try `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)`. How do you run cmake?

Comment: @KamilCuk it didn't work. I'm running cmake from the terminal. I'm including the library with a regular `add_subdirectory(mylib)` in my `main_project`.